# How to concatenate two sap.ui.model.Filter in JSON model?

Tags: sapui5

I have a JSON model like this:

```
{
    "VEHICLES": [
        {
            "vehicleId": "0001",
            "routeName": "Ginza Line"
        },
        {
            "vehicleId": "0002"
            "routeName": "Another Line"
        }
}
```

I am implementing a sort function like this:

```
onSearch : function (oEvent) {
    var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");

    if (sQuery) {
        var oFilter1 = new Filter("vehicleId", function(value) {
            return value.includes("sQuery");
        });

        var oFilter2 = new Filter("routeName", function(value) {
            return value.includes("sQuery");
        });

        var allFilter = new Filter([oFilter1, oFilter2], false});
        var list = this.getView().byId("masterList");
        list.getBinding("items").filter(allFilter);
    } 
}
```

When I input "000" in search field, I am expecting to return both data items, but it returns none. Why?

I have tried single  "vehicleId" filter, it worked.

I have also tried

```
var allFilter = new Filter({
    filters: [oFilter1, oFilter2], 
    and: false  //OR
});
```

But allFilter.bAnd returned `undefined`, I am confused.

Ref:

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/96804e3315ff440aa0a50fd290805116.html#loio50357d719b35439984348080bcbb14a4

https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1442

Comment: Is the above code just a minimal example? Otherwise, `new Filter("vehicleId", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)` should be used instead of a custom filter function in this case. Here is an [example](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5295470d7eee46c1898ee46c1b9ad763.html). UI5 will then take care of normalizing and capitalizing the search query which makes filtering easier and less error-prone.

Comment: @boghyon, yes, that also works! I thought `FilterOperator.Contains` only works for odata model, I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small mistake. You are checking if the `vehicleId` [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the string `"sQuery"`. Remove the quotes around *sQuery* and the filters will work fine.

```
value.includes(sQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I found that search in `routeName` did not work, then I found that all `value` captured by fnTest function are in the upper case. Do you know why?

Comment: @Tina: If we follow the callback traces, we can see that the string value is being ["normalized" and uppercased by the `FilterProcessor` module](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.46/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/FilterProcessor.js#L96) (That FilterProcessor is invoked by our ListBinding module). IMO, this behavior should be documented somewhere in the API reference but it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

according to API [document](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.ListBinding.html#filter). Put the parameter to Array

```
list.getBinding("items").filter([allFilter]);
```

@boghyon found from the source code [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.46/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/ClientListBinding.js#L183) that it is actually got converted to Array

Comment: It doesn't actually matter since [UI5 will put the single filter instance in an array](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.46/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/ClientListBinding.js#L183) if it's not already in it.

Comment: Good finding! @boghyon

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @boghyon and @suryabhan mourya, I changed the `fnTest` function to

```
var oFilter1 = new Filter("vehicleId", function(value) {
    return value.includes(sQuery.toUpperCase());
});
```

and it's working!