# "Cannot Read property sPath of undefined" when calling .read with filters

Tags: sapui5

I want to execute an OData Get request with filter from SAPUI5. The OData URL would look as follows:

> /sap/opu/odata/MAT_SRV/Get_MATSet?$filter=(Plant eq 'A1HG') and (MaterialType eq 'PS01') and ((MaterialNumber eq '61345280') or (MaterialNumber eq '61345280'))

Here, I have created the filter array for the OData service (`oDataFilter` in the example below) as follows:

```js
var oPlant = new Filter("Plant", FilterOperator.EQ, "A1HG");
var oPlantFilter = new Filter({
  filters: [oPlant],
  and: true
});
var oMatType = new Filter("MaterialType", FilterOperator.EQ, "PS01");
var oMatTypeFilter = new Filter({
  filters: [oMatType],
  and: true
});
var oMaterialNumberFilter = this._getMatNumbers(); //GET ALL MATERIAL NUMBER FILTERS SEPERATED By OR
var oDataFilter = new Filter({
  filters: [
    oPlantFilter,
    oMatTypeFilter,
    oMaterialNumberFilter
  ],
  and: true
});
BackEndModel.read("/Get_MATSet", {
  filters: oDataFilter,
  success: jQuery.proxy(this.fSuccess, this),
  error: jQuery.proxy(this.fError, this)
});
```

```js
_getMatNumbers: function() {
  var aTokens = this.byId("Mat_MultiInput").getTokens(); //ITERATE THROUGH EACH VALUES ENTERED BY USER
  var aMatFilter = [];
  for (var i in aTokens) {
    aMatFilter.push(new Filter("MaterialNumber", FilterOperator.EQ, aTokens[i].getKey()));
  }
  var oFilter = new Filter({ filters: aMatFilter, and: false });
  return oFilter;
}
```

However, I got the following error while execution:

> Cannot Read property sPath of undefined.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Or guide with the filter expression to be passed to the OData service which corresponds to the filter values mentioned in the OData URL?

Answer (score 1):

I looked up one of my codings with filters and found "my" oDataFilter to be an array. So try this:

```js
var oDataFilter = [
  new Filter({
    filters: [
      oPlantFilter,
      oMatTypeFilter,
      oMaterialNumberFilter
    ],
    and: true
  })
];
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer (although I wouldn't use `new Array`). The `filters` parameter in the read method actually awaits an array [in contrast to the `filter` method from the binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467187/how-to-concatenate-two-sap-ui-model-filter-in-json-model/43468201#comment73991902_43468196). Otherwise, UI5 throws the Error.

Comment: Futu - You are really my savior. Your solution was the catch which I could not see anywhere. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It worked

Comment: @SAPLearner Please, [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer to inform others that your problem got solved by this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since in your **oPlantFilter** and **oMatTypeFilter** contains only one filter criteria ypu can directly use them inside the **oDataFilter** as shown below. I hope it will help you to solve the problem. And one more thing concentrate on the **path** or **property** name with their **data type**.

```
var oPlantFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 'A1HG');
var oMatTypeFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("MaterialType", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 'PS01');
var oMaterialNumberFilter = this._getMatNumbers();

var oDataFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({ 
    filters: [oPlantFilter, oMatTypeFilter, oMaterialNumberFilter], 
    and: true 
});

BackEndModel.read( "/Get_MATSet", {
    filters: oDataFilter,
    success: jQuery.proxy(this.fSuccess, this),
    error: jQuery.proxy(this.fError, this) 
});

_getMatNumbers: function() {
    var aTokens = this.byId("Mat_MultiInput").getTokens();
    var aMatFilter = [];
    for (var i in aTokens) {
        aMatFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("MaterialNumber", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, aTokens[i].getKey())); 
    }
    var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({ 
        filters: aMatFilter, 
        and: false
    });
    return oFilter;
}
```